# JS SDK from Facebook stop working with this error in the console

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-login

Im finishing a webview project with android studio that loads a site... everithing was working OK when suddenly the button of login from facebook stop working and this error appear in the Console:
[image]

login script:

```
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('1');

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.

      testAPI();
    } else {

    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {
    console.log('2');

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    console.log('3');
    FB.init({
      appId      : '00000',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v3.2'
    });



  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function testAPI() {

    FB.api('/me?fields=email,name,first_name,last_name,gender',
    function(response) {


      $.ajax({
        url: "loginSave.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {id:response.id,
          email:response.email,
          name1:response.name,
          name2:'',
          gender:response.gender} ,
        success: function (response) {
           window.location.href = 'principal.php';
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });


    });
  }
```

Is a facebook error on her librarys o is something more i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent bug report for this, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/378853882892232/ - but it seems like the issue is resolved by now, according to the comments on that report.

If you are still experiencing this issue, file a new report (and maybe mention the existing one in it - that one is already closed, so if you just commented on that, it might get overlooked.)